# How to remove object key value of an object array?

Tags: javascript

I have an object array with object key value.

```
arr = [obj1:{name:"Jack", surname:"Peralto"}, obj2:{name:"Husnu", surname:"White"}]
```

I do not want to see **obj1** and **obj2** labels. Because of these labels I could not use a word template package.

So I want to convert it to this form.

```
arr = [{name:"Jack", surname:"Peralto"}, {name:"Husnu", surname:"White"}]
```

.map function does not work at first array.

> *arr.map(o=>o)*

Why I have an array like this? I should use reduce function and **obj1** and **obj2** labels are key value when I create object array. Now I don't need them.

Comment: An array can't have keys like `obj1`. Are you sure `arr` is actually an array and not an object?

Comment: I used reduce function for an array and made accumulator an array. It produced an array of objects with key value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you fix the syntax errors in your code (`[obj1:{...` is not a valid data structure) you can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get at the nested objects.

```js
const obj = {
  obj1: {
    name: "Jack",
    surname: "Peralto"
  },
  obj2: {
    name: "Husnu",
    surname: "White"
  }
};

console.log(Object.values(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

its not the right syntax of array you have used  array don't have key value pair

use this syntax if you are using object of objects with key value pair

```
const obj = {
  obj1: {
    name: "Jack",
    surname: "Peralto"
  },
  obj2: {
    name: "Husnu",
    surname: "White"
  }
};
```

or use this an array contains object

```
arr = [
{name:"Jack", surname:"Peralto"},
 {name:"Husnu", surname:"White"}
]
```